# Move fields from table to local table based on structure

Tags: dynamic-programming, abap, sap-data-dictionary

I customized the table KNVV. The append structure includes a structure where I actually defined all my custom fields. Lets call it zz_knvv_app_s.

A function pool, used to get and set the custom fields, has a function called ZSD_FOO_GET_DATA. It is exporting structure es_knvv TYPE knvv.

My current solution works, but is kind of stupid:

```
FUNCTION ZSD_FOO_GET_DATA.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Lokale Schnittstelle:
*"  EXPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(ES_KNVV) TYPE  KNVV
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
  es_knvv-zzfoo = knvv-zzfoo.
  es_knvv-zzbar = knvv-zzbar.
  es_knvv-zzbaz = knvv-zzbaz.
 " there are actually many more fields...
ENDFUNCTION.
```

What I am looking for is something like that:

- loop through KNVV
- assign the custom fields that are defined in my dictionary structure zz_knvv_aps_s...
- ... from KNVV to ES_KNVV
- something similary is also required for ZSD_FOO_GET_DATA

I am kind of new to ABAP. I think about looping and field symbols, but cant get it right. How would you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a [named include](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/EN/8d/bb6507967111d295b600a0c929b3c3/content.htm):

- create a structure - let's say `ZZ_MY_KNVV_FIELDS`
- KNVV has an append structure `ZZ_KNVV_APP_S`
- `ZZ_KNVV_APP_S` has a single entry `.INCLUDE` `ZZ_MY_KNVV_FIELDS` with a group name `ZZ_MY_FIELDS`
- same for any other output structure

You can then address all of your fields using `KNVV-ZZ_MY_FIELDS` as a structure of type `ZZ_MY_KNVV_FIELDS`

Comment: Named include works perfectly, thank you! It is just one line, how beautiful :-)